# German Umlaut in Matlab function not displayed properly

Tags: matlab, text, encoding

I run some matlab function and after upgrading to a new computer, MATLAB 2017b is not able to do string comparison containing umlaut because all the umlaut are dispalyed as ?. See below:

```
strcmp(factor_struct.conditions(i,k),'gr?sser als')
```

Chaning ? to ö does not work as matlab seems not able to display properly this character.

Is there a set-up to change in order to be able to read that type of charachters?

Comment: What is your OS?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by changing indeed the OS language format.